# Why lpOptional parameter of WinHttpSendRequest is not const?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winhttp

Is there any reason at all why `lpOptional` parameter of [WinHttpSendRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384110.aspx) function is not const? Is it safe to assume that the data pointed to by `lpOptional` parameter will not be modified by `WinHttpSendRequest` function (and pass a pointer to readonly memory to this function)?

Comment: I don't think API changes the data block or otherwise requires write access. Looks like it's missing for no reason (since times when `const`ness was not given much attention).

Comment: @Roman "Looks like it's missing for no reason" - my thoughts exactly, I should have went straigh to MS Connect to post a bug report.

Comment: If you attach Connect ticket number/link here, I will go vote up for it.

Comment: @Roman http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783691/lpoptional-parameter-of-winhttpsendrequest-function-is-not-const I'll update this question once MS clarifies the issue.